# Replace DOM content with jQuery reset other forms

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm currently working on a ASP.NET MVC 4 application. In a view, I display three Partials which are in fact AJAX forms.

Main view partial inclusion :

```
<div class="details-div">
    <h5>Section name</h5>
    <div id="sectionView">
        @Html.Action("Index", "Section")
    </div>
</div>
```

Partial view content :

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Update", "Section", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "sectionView",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    }))
    {
        // Form content

        <div class="inline-block-bottom">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save changes" />
        </div>
    }
```

Controller method :

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(SectionModel _sectionModel)
{
    // Update
    // Get updated

    return PartialView("Index", updatedSectionModel);
}
```

My problem is : when I submit form, all others forms on the page are reset. Values which aren't saved are removed from inputs and replaced with initial content, **even if they are not part of the form I submitted**.

If somebody has an hint about this issue...

Regards.

Comment: Please check how many ajax request performs in browser console.

Comment: Do you have included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` twice??

Comment: `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` is included only one time, in the container page. The partials do not use the layout, where I include the scripts.

Comment: And the request is emitted once.